# How to use the 'optgroup' html tag in an f.select? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I use the 'optgroup' html tag in an f.select?

Inside a search form I have the following field:

```
<%= f.select :location, ["San Francisco, USA", "Mountain View, USA", "London, UK", "Stockholm, Sweden"] %>
```

How to add optgroup in that, so it would become like:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option value="London, UK">London, UK</option>
    <option value="Stockholm, Sweden">Stockholm, Sweden</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="USA">
    <option value="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA</option>
    <option value="Mountain View, USA">Mountain View, USA</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= grouped_options = [['Europe',["London, UK", "Stockholm, Sweden"]], ['USA', ["San Francisco, USA", "Mountain View"]]] %>


<%= f.select :location, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options) %>
```